"a less frequency" or "a lower frequency"

Is there an English adverb that describes a less/lower frequency
than "occasionally" and does not have a negative connotation?

Which sounds idiomatic in this sentence, less or lower?
I have seen "lower frequency" used several times, but only in scientific contexts.

We say a lower frequency, not a less frequency.  Adverbs with this meaning could be infrequently and seldom.  These adverbs don’t have negative connotations unless we use them in sentences that convey such negativity.
He seldom makes mistakes.
He seldom does things correctly.
